# JQuery JavaScript, reload page before changePage, doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, reload

I'm trying to force an update of my jQuery page before I want to change the page.

Code looks like this:

```
function popupOrRedirect2() {
    location.reload();
    var content = document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').innerHTML;
    if (content > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage("http://localhost:8080/application/test");
    } else {
        $("#popupDialog4").popup("open");
    }
}
```

I need to read a value from a hidden div, but the div gets updated only after the page is getting reloaded. I must ensure to have the latest value.

The problem is, it doesn't work. If I remove the `location.reload()` it works... but it doesn't have the newest value.

Any hint on how to achieve the behavior that I want?

I'm using jQuery mobile  1.8.3.

Comment: As soon as you call `location.reload()` your page is going to refresh and any changes you apply afterwards will be lost. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: The page gets updated by some jsp code after refreshing. I need the the updated value (invisible div) to determine if it should redirect to a special page or just showing a popup.

Comment: nvm, it will be refactored. I will write a new rest service for this. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way might be to use URL params to determine whether to reload.

Instead of:

```
location.reload()
```

you could do:

```
if (location.search !== '?reloaded=1') {
  location.search = "reloaded=1"; //triggers a reload once
}
```